# Two or more hosts in traceroute answer

Tags: linux, networking, internet, wide-area-network, traceroute

Hi I have strange behavior of a traceroute to one of my public IP's
In one of a line I have multiple hostnames with timing
like in the folowing example, on the 5th line

```
traceroute to dns.abc.com (111.222.333.444), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  router.example.com (192.168.0.1)  1.137 ms  0.712 ms  0.641 ms
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  212.2.102.1 (212.2.102.1)  39.234 ms  38.799 ms  38.762 ms
5  wawbal-i1-BE11.plusnet.pl (212.2.102.189)  45.306 ms pozche-i2-BE15.plusnet.pl (212.2.102.214)  38.787 ms  38.667 ms
6  wawbal-i2-BE12.plusnet.pl (212.2.102.210)  45.495 ms  35.135 ms  34.872 ms
7  xe-2-0-0-48.r5.isp-rs.thinx.atman.pl (212.91.0.13)  34.402 ms  39.241 ms  40.592 ms
......
```

has anyone seen anything like this before ?
What is it means ?

Much thanks for an answer.
M

Comment: May be a CNAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that there are two (or more) redundant physical links between points 4 and 6. If used, each of them will show up at point 5. Traceroute by default sends three probes. In this case one of the probes used one link, and two of them used the other.